# jQuery: pass data with $.getScript?

Tags: jquery

Can i pass data to the function youtubeFetchDataCallback in this:

```
$.getScript( 'gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/… echo $m; ?>?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=youtubeFetchDataCallback' );
```

e.g i pass data "mode" then inside the function i can alert(mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows it with an anonymous function; note that the URL is changed to use `?` for the callback, so jQuery chooses a function name.  However, you can also used a named function in the same scope.  Either way, `mode` is closed in to the function.

```
var mode = ...;
$.getScript( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/… echo $m; ?>?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function()
{
  alert(mode);
});
```